# What causes a dark curvy line to appear in a photo of sky?

Tags: image-quality

[image]

I think it might have to do with the uv but I have a uv filter on

Answer (score 5):

The image sensor chip at the back of the camera, behind the lens, is dirty, it has a filamentary object or a human hair resting on its surface. The sensor is protected by a thin over-glass. This is what is contaminated. You can prove this for yourself. What you are seeing is the shadow of this contaminate. This shadow of the hair is indistinct because the lens is set to a moderately wide-open setting. If you take a picture on manual setting with the f-number set to f/22 or f/16, the shadow will be far more visible. Clean the sensor cover glass as others have told you.

Answer (score 3):

That is a hair, either on the rear surface of the lens or somewhere on the sensor. You should clean both, gently.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out your sensor is dirty. You have at least two other visible specks:

[image]

The more closed (the higher the f-number) the lens is(*), the more visible the dust specs are, so you usually discover them in the sky of you photos taken on a sunny day.

(*) and for this you can't beat a pinhole lens

Answer (score 2):

This is because on your sensor or back of your lens you have thread. Inspect the lens and use air blower to remove it. About sensor check if your camera have dust removal function and use it. Also you can carefully use air blower on the sensor.